# Check if PickupItemEvent ItemStack is cobblestone?

Tags: java, listener, minecraft, bukkit

```
@EventHandler
public void pickup(InventoryPickupItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getItem().getItemStack().isSimilar(new ItemStack(Material.COBBLESTONE))) {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("doesn't work yet");
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. I've also tried .equals similarly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's already an answer, but I thought I'd explain: you can't compare ItemStacks, that class does not override `equals()` or the `==` operator, you have to compare the contents directly.

Comment: Thanks! This clarifies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a material against another, as it's a fixed enum value.

```
Material m = myItemstack.getType();
if (m.equals(Material.COBBLESTONE)) //IS COBBLE
```

And also, if the data is also important

```
MaterialData data = myItemstack.getData();
if (data.equals(/*ANOTHER MATERIAL DATA*/)) //Also the same data
```

Comment: Do you also know a method to get the data value? Like spruce wooden planks for example.

Comment: Updated answer ;)